# Asp.net Mvc 4 Many to Many relationship ViewModels

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I read [this](http://codenodes.wordpress.com/2013/04/13/saving-many-to-many-data-in-mvc4-and-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3/) article.

My question is how can i get assigned courses for users in  Index.cshtml ?

I add  `@Html.DisplayFor(modeltItem => item.Courses)` to Index view and it shows the Ids of the courses correctly.

I want to see descriptions (or names) of courses.

I tried to use CourseDescription in UserProfileViewModel but I don't know how to use it in controller index action (in the article).

Comment: I didn't find any Index action on that post, just Edit and Detail. Did you type wrong?

Comment: @TiagoBrenck the post has also part 1 [link](http://codenodes.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/saving-many-to-many-data-in-mvc4-and-ef-4-1-code-first-part-1/)  and part 2  [link](http://codenodes.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/saving-many-to-many-data-in-mvc4-and-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2/). UserProfileController Index action is in part 1